# Ticketing norms for Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, russia, proof-of-onward-travel

I am an Indian citizen. I will travel few to Austria, Hungary, Czechoslovakia, Poland and Germany. My entry will be through Vienna and exit through Berlin. After Schengen my next destination will be Russia. I will have a one way ticket to Vienna and my exit ticket will be to Russia from germany.i will also have a Russian visa issued from India. Will I face any problem for not returning to India directly? Secondly, in the Russian visit Visa everything is written in Russian, the contents of which is hard to understand. In such a scenario would I face any problem from the point of boarding,entry and exit out of Schengen area

Comment: Schengen authorities don’t care where you’re going to, they only care that you are leaving the Schengen zone completely.

Comment: Eh? All of the Russian visas I have seen have field names printed in Russian and English, the traveler's name written in Cyrillic and Latin script. The only parts not translated are the nationality, purpose of visit and inviting agency, but the airline doesn't really care about that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your planned trip follows the general lines of your visa application or is not the first of a multiple entry visa, the border official will not mind whichever route you use.
Any entry and exit point and any departure point towards the Schengen zone is allowed.

For your next destination you need prove you can enter, which your Russia visa does. Border officials and airline staff are used to this kind of visa and know how to check it.

Small point, Czechia and Slovakia have been separate countries since 1993.